# Chrome Extension reload behaves differently post-packaging

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a tab rotation extension. Simply switches to the next tab every few seconds (configurable, named `interval`/`newInterval`). When I load the unpacked extension, everything works fine but when I test the extension post-packaging, the reload functionality isn't triggering. I clear the interval and reload the extension. The `onInstalled.addListener` triggers with the unpacked extension when I call `runtime.reload()`, but doesn't with the packed version. Any ideas?

// rotationOptions.js   (extension options script)

```
intervalSaveButton.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval();
    const newInterval = intervalInput.value;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'rotationInterval': newInterval}, function() {
        chrome.runtime.reload();
    });
};
```

// rotateTabs.js   (background script)

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'rotation': true});
    chrome.storage.sync.get('rotationInterval', function(data) {
        if (!data || data.rotationInterval === null || data.rotationInterval === undefined) {
            chrome.storage.sync.set({'rotationInterval': 5000});
            setInterval(cycleNextTab, 5000);
        } else {
            setInterval(cycleNextTab, data.rotationInterval);
        }
    });
});

function cycleNextTab () {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('rotation', function (data) {
        if (data.rotation) {
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tab) {
                const currentTabIndex = tab[0].index;
                chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
                    const nextIndex = (currentTabIndex + 1) === tabs.length ? 0 : currentTabIndex + 1;
                    const nextTabId = tabs[nextIndex].id;
                    chrome.tabs.update(nextTabId, { active: true });
                    chrome.tabs.update(nextTabId, {url: tabs[nextIndex].url});
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Apparently unpacked extensions use a different installation  mechanism that triggers onInstalled on reloading. I would consider it a bug, which you were abusing. You'll have to implement the functionality differently. Reloading is a weird solution anyway. Try using messaging, chrome.alarms API, event pages, and all the other straightforward stuff.

Comment: @wOxxOm alright thanks, I'll look into those approaches